# MonoTouch. Push Notifications, aps-environment

Tags: xamarin.ios, push

i'm trying to implement push notifications in my app, but it tells me “no valid aps-environment entitlement found for application”

I set the identifier correctly and even added an "aps-environment" entry in my Info.plist, but still it gives me this error message.

The bundle identifier is set correctly and i installed the certificates from the provisioning portal.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you using a `com.yourcompany.*` provisioning profile by chance?

Comment: de.mycompany.appname yes

Comment: If you are using a wildcard it would cause problems, does not sound like you are though.  Can you try running `codesign -dvvvv --entitlements - /path/to/App.app`?  You should see `aps-environment=production`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In "normal" environment ( macosx + xcode) I am selecting the Project, and at Targets I need to enable the Entitlements, like this:
[image: screenshot]
and need to be the provisioning profile with my device UDID added

Comment: this is what i have too,still it gives me the error i mentioned above upon registration

Comment: this I need + the latest provisioning profile need to contain my UDID. At this point doesn't matter if is Push notifications are on used or not. Try to clean up: remove provisioning profile from xcode, itunes, keychain, remake the request submit the certif, import and at signing the build select the new one?

Comment: removing everything and downloading+adding it again did the trick. thanks for your help :)

Comment: np, you will need to do again that, when you will use the Push certificates too at server side! and also you can't use from maxcosx, you need to buy the server version or go to host to windows/linux, or pay 15.99 euro for server version :( Bloody Apple